# Get exact couchdb version

Tags: couchdb

I have a server running couchdb, and I would like to know what version I am running.  I know it is 1.2.0, but I want to know 1.2.0-X.  I have looked through some of the source files for this info, but I can't seem to find it.  Is there any way I can find this information?

Thanks!

Comment: What does you mean by `-X`? I'm pretty sure releases are done on a simple "x.y.z" basis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can make authenticated requests, you can directly get the version number by using the api "_config" handler:

`http://yourserver:5984/_config/vendor/version`

Answer (score 8):

You can just query `http://yourserver:5984/` which should return the result.

Quoting from the [API Docs](https://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/server/common.html#get--)

**Request:**

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Host: localhost:5984
```

**Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Content-Length: 179
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 10 Aug 2013 06:33:33 GMT
Server: CouchDB (Erlang/OTP)

{
    "couchdb": "Welcome",
    "uuid": "85fb71bf700c17267fef77535820e371",
    "vendor": {
        "name": "The Apache Software Foundation",
        "version": "1.3.1"
    },
    "version": "1.3.1"
}
```

Comment: But what happens if your old version of Couch DB was just hacked and some ransomware has been installed and it won't start.. how does one know what version they have in that case? Asking for a friend....